# What's the best way to convert a Date to a DateTime in the current timezone in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime

I'm using Rails 4.2. I have a `Date` that I'd like to convert to a `DateTime`. If I use the existing `to_datetime` method, it converts it in GMT. (I've looked at threads for about an hour now and couldn't find this exact problem so apologies in advance if it exists!)

```
irb(main):030:0> Date.current
=> Wed, 19 Aug 2015
irb(main):031:0> Date.current.to_datetime
=> Wed, 19 Aug 2015 00:00:00 +0000
```

If I then try to use `in_time_zone`, it converts it to the current time zone but also subtracts the offset from the date.

```
irb(main):032:0> Date.current.to_datetime.in_time_zone
=> Tue, 18 Aug 2015 17:00:00 PDT -07:00
```

How can I convert an existing `Date` to a `DateTime` in the current time zone?

Comment: What's the "correct" time zone? What does `Time.zone` return?

Comment: Changed from "correct" to "current", which is PST.

Comment: Does `Time.zone` return `PST` then?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's the best answer I could come up with.

```
Time.zone.at(Date.current.to_time).to_datetime
```

Comment: but local timezone may not be the same as rails timezone as set in `application.rb` with config, so i think `Time.zone.at` may still be a better choice in rails environment

Comment: Oh, that's a really good point -- I think that's why I ended up not using it, because it worked for me in local, but not in prod.

Comment: This doesn't return the beginning of the day in the current time zone. It is offset based on the local time zone. See Kelly Corrigan's answer.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue, and I did this:

```
Time.use_zone("Europe/Berlin") do
  midnight = Time.zone.parse(@date.to_s)
end
```

Which basically re-creates the date as a Time instance while being in the target timezone, at midnight, without "moving" the Time instance around.

Comment: This one worked for me, but I didn't have to use the `Time.use_zone` block because the app already have the right timezone configured. 
It was basically `beginning_of_day = Time.zone.parse(@date.to_s)`

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer didn't work for me because `Date.current.to_time` converted the date to my `:local` timezone, which is UTC, instead of my configured timezone, which is PST.

Instead, I used `Date.current.in_time_zone.to_datetime`, which I found here: https://www.varvet.com/blog/working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails/